# Trying to integrate Views with CiviCRM but cannot see the code

Tags: drupal-views

I am trying to integrate Views with CiviCRM but cannnot see the code in the CMS Datbase section to add to the settings.php file. I am stuck on step 5. Has anyone come across this issue?

The steps are here - http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Views3+Integration

Comment: If you are using one database for both Civi and Drupal, then you don't need the code for Views integration.

Comment: Using different databases for them. Thanks pmoz

Comment: so are you saying that at /civicrm/admin/setting/uf?reset=1 you see nothing? any other indications that your drupal<->civi linkages is problematic? do you have a drupal user id on the contact summary screen and can click it to go to the user record, and vice versa, on drupal user record do you have the civi Name and Address profile showing, and the link back to the civi record?

Comment: That is right pete. I can click between both civicrm user and the drupal user record and it works fine. I cannot see any linkage problem. I see the link to the contact dashboard on the drupal user field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. You need to go to your civicrm.settings file first and then add the drupal base URL in the section where it says add your drupal URL and then you will see the code.

1. Follow the steps in the link for Views.
2. In the civicrm.settings.php file there will a comment around line 58 which asks to enter the Content Management System (CMS) database connection details. Once this is entered the views should show up.

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: surprised that wasn't causing other havoc

Comment: Thanks Joe. Pete we are really beginning to integrate CiviCRM into websites more seamlessly. I am sure that it would cause some chaos in the longer run if not fixed.

Comment: @SohalKhatwani I'm having the same problem but I'm not understanding your solution. Which line did you edit in `civicrm.settings.php` ?

The way this response is written it's like replacing the MySQL URL with the base URL which doesn't make sense at all. Can offer more detailed instructions? ty.

Comment: Hi @atmosx. There are a couple of steps to get the CiviCRM data into Drupal Views. I will add another detailed answer below.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. My problem was not installing views at all. Works as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

Sohal, see this video from CiviCON Denver 2015 as well - it might help -
[CiviCON Denver- CiviCRM Drupal Integration Showcase](https://youtu.be/i2GpnrVGdrc?list=PLjSU7YfE0E01HW7JPVAI80XDI0sgOSPDs)

Comment: Joe the video is great. Learned a fair bit from it. However, no solution to the code.

Comment: Sohal, oh well. A question - why are you not using just one database for both CiviCRM and Drupal?

Comment: Hi Joe, we prefer to keep the database separate as some of our clients do not go for CiviCRM and once integrated we find it quite hard to remove CiviCRM from Drupal when the database is the same.